# Django: How can I list all available RSS feeds of app?

Tags: django, rss

I know how to create a new RSS feed using Django. However, I'd like to provide a page with an overview over all available RSS feeds the website provides.

How can I get all the RSS feeds that are available in Django? Unfortunately, I could not find any answer yet.

Comment: There several different ways of creating a RSS feed using django. May you please show us how you solved it? Without this information it is nearly impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Using the first example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/syndication/

Comment: Interesting - I was not aware of this app. Your question would be much better and worth up-voting, if you include the example code, together with the link directly - not only in the comments. This way someone can see where the question is about without additional efforts.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to just create a list somewhere in your code and manually add all your URL names. As long as there are just a few - I would recommend this approach, because this way you can easily add further meta information which you might want to have to render the list. And it keeps your code clean.

A generic approach for dozens of RSS feeds needs to introspect the URLs configuration of your project, because this is the only place where the information is available. You might try to create a view that parses the url configuration and add the collected information to the render context.

**untested example**

```
from projectapp import urls
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed


def find_feed_url_names(patterns, feeds = []):
    """
    Recursively searches in all URLs for callbacks that are an instance of Feed

    Returns a list including all url names
    """
    for p in patterns:
        if p.callback:
            if isinstance(p.callback, Feed):
                # we found a route that points to an RSS or Atom feed.
                feeds.append(p.name)
        # if no callback is defined it is an include - search there, too
        else:  
            feeds = find_feed_url_names(p.url_patterns, feeds=feeds)  # recursion!
    return feeds


class ListRSSFeedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'foobar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['feed_url_names'] = find_feed_url_names(urls.url_pattern)
      return context
```

*Note:* The code to iterate over the url configuration is inspired by [In Django, how do I introspect application urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733413/in-django-how-do-i-introspect-application-urls)

This should work, because [`Feed`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/syndication/views.py#L29) itself is a callable and you don't need to call `to_view()` on it.

In your template you can now use the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to generate links pointing to the collected URLs.

Comment: I just realized the you only want those for one app. Just import `urls` from this app instead of urls from the project in this case.